# Cannot get ajax to respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a simple ajax call, and convert the returned JSON string into a javascript array. This is getting the correct values.. The code does not work. I want to simply return the json string and convert it to an array..

```
function getData(){
    var barcode = $('#idQuery').val();
    alert(barcode);
    var test = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://example.com/public/ruser/family',
        data: {barcode: barcode},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    alert(test);
}
```

This is the response from the browser if I put it in url.

```
[[{"age":10,"id":"1","name":"John Doe","points":"4275653423"}]]
```

Comment: What is considered 'right' by you? If your code works, then where is the question here?

Comment: It doesn't work. Because the alert does not go off. And I know I'm sending in correct data, because I've tried it by typing it in the url manually.

Comment: Try debugging it in the developer console and see what's coming across.

Comment: Is there any error popping up in the console of your browser? (F12 in Chrome, get Firebug in Firefox).

Comment: No but it alerts at the end, object js object. Which is not by the success.

Comment: Says in the network it is returning a 303.

Comment: Well, looks like you're trying to send json by GET method. Is your server expecting a get request to receive the data? Because GET requests don't have a message body, the data therefore is added to query string.

Comment: See the edit in my answer.

Comment: You're using GET request and looks like POST is more appropriate here - look my answer below

Comment: The response from the server is invalid. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Once the response is valid json, and the ajax success callback executes, in order to convert the json string returned by the server into a javascript object use `JSON.parse()`

```
success: function (data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj.age);
}
```

Note: Only the more modern browsers natively support json serialization (JSON.parse). To ensure that older browsers support this functionality, Douglas Crockford's json2.js is recommended:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Just download and include the above in your page and you're good to go.

Edit: The response from the server includes an array with another array inside of it that contains the object with your data:

`[[{"age":10,"id":"1","name":"John Doe","points":"4275653423"}]]`

The server needs to respond with a json string that just contains the object:

`'{"age":10,"id":"1","name":"John Doe","points":"4275653423"}'`

Finally, the server must respond with the correct content type, 'application/json'

Edit: In your comments you said the server was returning 303, which is a redirect. The url you are using in your ajax call redirects to another url that returns the data you want. You need to use the url that returns the data. The url needs to match exactly. For instance, `http://example.com/public/ruser/family` is not the same as `http://example.com/public/ruser/family/`

Edit: final code:

```
function getData(){
    var barcode = $('#idQuery').val();

    var test = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://example.com/public/ruser/family.json',
        data: { barcode: barcode },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(obj.age);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using fuelphp's REST controller to respond with JSON. And I know it's returning valid JSON.

Comment: The URL that returns the data is example.com/public/ruser/family.json?barcode=22222

Comment: Ok I misinterpreted what you were trying to do, the above should work.

Comment: The key is that the server was returning 303, a redirect. Redirects only work in the browser. You need to change the url to be the exact url of whatever your current url redirects to.

Comment: if `http://example.com/public/ruser/family.json` is what's redirecting, then most likely your server is configured to redirect any request url that doesn't have a trailing slash. So you should try `http://example.com/public/ruser/family.json/` This is a common approach to url cannonicalization, which ensures that every resource on a server only has one single unique url.

Comment: Ok, is there a www in the url when you visit the url in a browser? eg: is it `http://example.com/public/ruser/family.json` or `http://www.example.com/public/ruser/family.json`

Comment: Also, as described in one of the other answers, the url you are requesting must be on the same domain. Otherwise, you have to use jsonp, or add response headers to the resource on the server in which it resides.

Comment: It's the same domain as what I'm requesting from.

Comment: I'm going to reiterate that the url needs to be exact, eg: with or without the "www", and with or without the trailing slash. You can even try using a relative url instead of the full url with the domain name. If you are sure that it's correct, check the network section in browser tools again to see if the response is still a 303.

Comment: Other than that, it could be a problem on the server side. For example, your ajax method is expecting json to be returned from the server. If the server responds with invalid json, that would cause an error.

Comment: Also, in browser dev tools check console for any error messages.

Comment: The dev tools show it's returning an object with the data expected. And it gives a 200 success code.

Comment: That leads me to believe the json returned from the server is invalid

Comment: What's the parse error you got from trying the code from the other answer?

Comment: The server needs to return a json string in the format `"{ 'someVar': 'value' }"` Also, the server needs to response with `'content-type: application/json'`

Comment: I changed it, and it now replies.. "[{\"age\":7,\"id\":\"17907226\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"points\":\"63302122001254\"}]"

Comment: When I run this statement, alert(data); in the data function.. It alerts delayed, but it won't store in a separate variable.  It does put it in an alert, but it won't store it.. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData(){
    var barcode = $('#idQuery').val();
    alert(barcode);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "controller/action",
        data: {barcode: barcode},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

}
```

try above it should work let me know the progress................

Comment: When I get the post data of 'barcode' it returns empty. And I changed the code to work with post..

Comment: u then use $.getjson instead of $.ajax and u have to return json(something, json.getallowbehaviour) in the controller return.......if u have not got idea how to use getjson let me know

Comment: if you could type example.com/public/ruser/family.json?barcode=22222 into a browser, and it returned the data you want, then there is no reason you have to use post.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data provider on the same domain as the client that's using $.ajax?
If not, you need to ensure you're either using JSONP (which I can see you're not from your function), or that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the data provider is set to allow the client domain.

If it is a cross-origin issue then the success callback would never be called, you can test for the error by implementing the complete method for further debugging. (Note: console.log is much more useful for debugging than alert.)

See what this logs for you:

```
function getData(){
    var barcode = $('#idQuery').val();
    var test = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json",
        data: {barcode: barcode},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

            console.log(jqXHR)

            console.log("What's the issue? " + textStatus)
        }
    });
}
```

Also, if you use Chrome's Dev Tools (which you should, because they're awesome) any cross-domain errors are logged to the console. (Open it with F12 or right-click and Inspect Element.)

Comment: @RyanDawkins: You are supposed to change the url in his code to yours.

Comment: It doesn't say what the parse error is. But the last alert that stores the $.ajax return prints [obj javascript object]. Which I think is a JSONObject, how would I parse this?